# Black screen device does not work

Tags: windows-7, black-screen-of-death

A black screen appeared, when the system is running again appeared this message:

```
Problems Signature:
   Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
   OS version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
   Locale ID: 1053

Additional information about the problem:
   BCCode: 7a
   BCP1: FFFFF6FB80008000
   BCP2: FFFFFFFFC00000B5
   BCP3: 000000000F396880
   BCP4: FFFFF70001000000
   OS Version: 6_1_7601
   Service Pack: 1_0
   Product: 256_1
```

Comment: You need to tell us a lot more details of the issue for anyone to be able to help. What were you doing when it happened? Have any upgrades or new software been installed before it? Does the system work or not (title says not, but seems like it does)?

Comment: The problem occurred suddenly, after he stopped working on the device for some time.

Comment: have you check the HDD/cables?

Comment: Problem in the laptop. How can check the HDD/cables?

Comment: in this case, remove the HDD and insert the HDD again. Maybe you have a slack joint.

Answer (score 0):

You get the Bug Check [0x7A: KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> This bug check indicates that the requested page of kernel data from
>   the paging file could not be read into memory.

The error code C00000B5 in parameter 2 means that there is a timeout during the IO operation:

```
C:\Users\André>err C00000B5
# for hex 0xc00000b5 / decimal -1073741643
  STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT                                              ntstatus.h
# {Device Timeout}
# The specified I/O operation on %hs was not completed before
# the time-out period expired.
# 1 matches found for "C00000B5"
```

Check the [SMART Status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) of [your HDD](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html). Maybe your HDD dies. Also try (if you use a desktop PC) to connect the HDD to a different SATA port (with a new cable)